# Obtaining a cmap for color brewer palette

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, seaborn

How to obtain the cmap version of the palette that comes from `sns.color_palette()` function? For example, I can ask for the color brewer palette like this:

```
sns.color_palette('Blues')
```

but

```
sns.color_palette('Blues', as_cmap=True)
```

results in "TypeError: color_palette() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_cmap'".

I could of course use `sns.choose_colorbrewer_palette()`, which accepts `as_cmap` argument, but it only works in interactive mode (I can't ask it for `'Blues'` in the python script).

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Well, don't I need cmap for many matplotlib functions? Like `plot_surface` or `contour` etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the colormap in a matplotlib/seaborn function, simply pass the name (e.g., `plt.pcolormesh(..., cmap="Blues")`) and matplotlib will know what to do.

If you want the colormap object for some reason, it lives in the `matplotlib.cm` namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add something that was confusing for me.

For palettes that support it, if you set `as_cmap=True`, `seaborn` creates a color palette with 256 colors and then asks `mpl.ListedColorMap` to make an `mpl.ColorMap` (which will simply interpolate between the neighboring colors, treating them as if they split [0, 1] interval into equal parts). It makes sense that `seaborn` doesn't use the `n_colors` argument in this case because a `mpl.ColorMap` represents a function from [0, 1] into colors, and the more colors are used to create this with `mpl.ListedColorMap` the more precise the function is. (Presumably no need to go above 256 colors due for most applications?)

So converting a seaborn color palette to `mpl.ColorMap` can be done by generating 256 colors of the palette (assuming the palette is generated algorithmically of course, so it produces that many distinct colors) and then calling `mpl.ListedColorMap`. Of course, as @mwaskom pointed out one can simply use the `mpl.ColorMap` object from `mpl.cm` namespace.